# Where are the mobile devices in the Network panel coming from?

Tags: windows-10, security, home-networking

In Windows 10 the Network panel shows mobile devices I never connected to either my network or my computer. See image (just an example, could be Sony, LG, ...). They change from time to time.

My computer has only wired Ethernet and no wireless capabilities (BT, WiFi).

The WiFi home network is based on a OpenWRT install plus a Netgear extender they are protected with WPA2-PSK and firewall to the outside (very few ports open). No additional devices are listed as connected.

The modem by the provider offers a private Wired+WiFi for me plus a WiFi public for all his other customers. My OpenWRT is connected to the wired private network and not reachable by the other customers.

Where are they coming from?

[image]

Comment: Try disabling WPS (Wi-Fi Protected Setup) on all your APs, and disable the Windows Connect Now service (WCNCSVC) on your PC. If you can't reconfig the APs, just disable WCNCSVC on your PC. Does that fix it?

Comment: @Spiff WPS button is already disabled, it's the first thing I do. I will check the WCN.

Comment: I'm curious to know if shutting down WCNCSVC solved your problem.

Comment: @Spiff well from https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-networking/rogue-devices-showing-up-on-windows-8-network-in/2c61616e-bcbc-4a7a-9a66-eab68fae84cd it appears it's only cosmetic, they are never actually inside the network (still, seems strange to me). So no need to disable that service.

Comment: But it works too.